# Dynamic bootbox modals in meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, bootbox

I'm trying to create a basic app that dynamically renders thumbnails and associates a dynamically generated modal to each on click. I can't seem to figure out how to insert data from my mongo db into the bootbox alert, I know i need to run the query again, but I'm not sure how to retrieve the fields for that specific entry.

Here's the html template:

```
<template name="gallery">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
      <a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-toggle="#">
        <img src="{{img}}" alt="...">
          <div class="caption">
            <h5><center>{{name}}</center></h5>
          </div>
      </a>
    </div>
</template>
```

and here's the js.

```
Gallerys = new Mongo.Collection("gallerys");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Template.body.helpers({
    gallerys: function () {
      return Gallerys.find({}, {sort: {createdAt  :-1}});
    }
  });

  Template.body.events({
    "click a.thumbnail": function(e) {
      bootbox.alert(function(){
        return Gallerys.find();
      };
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you'll eventually move the overall gallery into its own template and tie the helper functions to that instead of to `body` but let's deal with the main issue, your body event handler needs to return the data context of an individual record, not a cursor. The click on the overall gallery should give you the context of an individual gallery item with the result that `this` will point to that document and `this._id` will be the `_id` of that document.

```
Template.body.events({
  "click a.thumbnail": function(e){
    bootbox.alert(function(){
      return Gallerys.findOne({_id: this._id});
    };
  }
});
```

I suspect you also want to be using `bootbox.dialog` and not just `bootbox.alert`